# Is it possible to call a function that needs a parameter, without it? On python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, conditional-statements

I'm learning to code on Python 3.x using Exercism. I have to code a conditional (on a secondary file) to return a string depending on a word sent from a main function:

**User function:**

```
def two_fer(name):
    if name:
        string = "One for " + name + ", one for me."
    else:
        string = "One for you, one for me."
    return string
```

**Main function:**

```
class TwoFerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_no_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer(), 'One for you, one for me.')

    def test_a_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer("Alice"), "One for Alice, one for me.")

    def test_another_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer("Bob"), "One for Bob, one for me.")
```

**The problem is that**, for the first condition in the main function, it calls `two_fer()` with no conditional, which results on a fail.

Main function is supposed to not be modified, is it any way to solve the problem only by the user function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a default value for the parameter?

Comment: Yes as mentioned above, you can add a default value by using in the parameters function(parameter = something) or you can use a lambda function to call a normal function with parameters

Comment: I think you need `def two_fer(name=""):`

Answer (score 2):

You can change:

```
def two_fer(name):
```

to:

```
def two_fer(name=None):
```

which will make name None by default

Answer (score 1):

If you give `name` a default value of `"you"`, you can call the function without an explicit argument *and* get rid of the `if` statement altogether.

```
def two_fer(name="you"):
    return "One for " + name + ", one for me"
```

or better yet,

```
def two_fer(name="you"):
    return "One for {}, one for me".format(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default parameter i.e None and check whether the function received any parameter or not.

**User Function:**

```
def two_fer(name = None):
    if name != None:
        string = "One for " + name + ", one for me."
    else:
        string = "One for you, one for me."
    return string
```

The above code will execute the else part if the method two_fer is called without any parameters.

Comment: Use `is` for comparing with `None`, i.e. `if name is not None:`

Answer (score 0):

Use a default parameter like following

```
def two_fer(name=None):
    if name:
        s = "One for " + name + ", one for me."
    else:
        s = "One for you, one for me."
return s
```

Also a tip, avoid assigning variable names as keywords for e.g. string in your case as it is a standard library and it is just a good practice to avoid it.